# When is next Monday?

Tags: date, version, coreutils

On my home computer (Xubuntu 14.04), I have

```
zev@home:~$ date +%F
2015-10-05

zev@home:~$ date +%F -d "next Monday"
2015-10-12
```

whereas at work (Red Hat 5.11), I have

```
zev@work:~$ date +%F
2015-10-05

zev@work:~$ date +%F -d "next Monday"
2015-10-05
```

(Note that today is Monday.) My initial guess was that the different interpretations of the phrase `next Monday` are due to the systems having different versions of the coreutil `date`:

```
zev@home:~$ date --version | head -2
date (GNU coreutils) 8.21
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

zev@work:~$ date --version | head -2
date (GNU coreutils) 5.97
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

My questions are:

- Is the difference in versions of the `date` program the sole cause, or is there something else about a system that will affect its interpretation of date strings?
- How can I know whether a system will have one interpretation or the other, without running the commands to check directly? If the only thing that affects the outcome is the version of `date`, then according to this unix.SE thread ([Which version of X introduced feature Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9935)) I should be able to find which version introduced the new behavior in a changelog for the `date` program, but I can't find anything remotely like that [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git) (maybe I'm just confused).

Comment: Could you temporarily install the older coreutils on your home computer to test it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did `rpm -qfl /bin/date` and looked through the list of files for a
changelog, and found `/usr/share/doc/coreutils/NEWS` and the following paragraph:

> - Noteworthy changes in release 7.4 (2009-05-07) [stable]
>
>   > Bug fixes.
>   >      date -d 'next mon', when run on a Monday, now prints the date
>   >     7 days in the future rather than the current day.  Same for any other
>   >     day-of-the-week name, when run on that same day of the week.
>   >     [This bug appears to have been present in "the beginning". ]